# how to detect a user tap on table view

Tags: iphone, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, tableview

i want to detect user touch on table view so that i can pass that particular section information to the next view to display it ...

how can i do it

Comment: can you please take a minute to rephrase / add to your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set your view controller as the delegate for the table view:

```
tableView.delegate = self;
```

Then implement the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`.  If you're just getting started, you should probably read the [UITableView programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html).